# Unable to extend ubuntu partiton

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to expand my Ubuntu partition, I booted up my LiveCD, opened GParted and freed some space. But when I'm trying to expand the partition, it doesn't show any free space. It does this only for the Ubuntu partition, other partitions can be expanded.

[image]

`/dev/sda11` is my Ubuntu partition. I'm also running a dual boot with Windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to expand the /dev/sda11 partition, you need to have free space just after the partition and presently you have /dev/sda5 exactly after.

What you need to do if move the /dev/sda5 partition just before /dev/sda8, then trying increasing the /dev/sda11 partition again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend the Ubuntu partition, or any partition for that matter, both partitions (existing and empty) have to be next to each other.  In your case `/dev/sda11`, and the unallocated space have an NTFS partition between them.

**Note:  When dealing with partitions always make sure that you have a current backup just in case anything goes wrong.**

Comment: How would I go about reordering the partitions? I can't seem to find any button for that, if even one exists. EDIT: Do I "Move / Resize" the NTFS partition and slide it all the way to right?

Comment: What's on `/dev/sda5`?

Comment: Hm, just some files and such, nothing I would necessarily need. I can move them somewhere else if that helps.

Comment: OK, then copy these files somewhere, delete the partition, extend `/dev/sda11`, create the `NTFS` partition afterwards, copy data back on.

Comment: I'm unable to delete it as `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda10` are mounted and I can't unmount them as they're LVM, would there be any work around?